# Changing table field in query from Ms access form

Tags: ms-access

I have data 19 tables in database I gathered then in one query with unique I'd to make compare between them let's consider inserted column AA from table wallet 31-12
I want to change wallet 31-12
To anther wallet using label form.
Thank you

I need to amend query table field using form label

Comment: Hi, Are you trying to change table name, table data, column name or column data. i.e  what is  wallet 31-12 I ?

Comment: Table name in query design view from form label

Comment: Say in query design view tabel field forms![data]![label2]

Comment: I doubt if table name can be changed like that.

Comment: So there is no way to solve this

Comment: Out of inquisitiveness, why would you want to change a table name using form values? Maybe if we understand better, other ways around it can be given to you.

Comment: Are these tables identical in structure? If so, should be one table with another field for a category value, such as WalletID. What is it you want to compare? How would changing table name in query make comparison? VBA can use DAO QueryDefs to modify query object.

Comment: Yes all tables have sme structure but every table for month like frost table for wallet-jan second table for wallet-feb and so on for 2022 year so I made relationship between tables in same query now if I need to get differance between first table and second one in sales I will set in table field first one wallet-jan in field name then I will set wallet-feb for second column table name that all in query design view but in case I need to see difference between wallet-mar and wallet-apr I have to change tabels manually in table field in query design view

Comment: I ask if I can change them by putting all tabels names in drop down list in form then make button to requery to update table field name